# Silverlight canvas freedraw underperforming

Tags: performance, silverlight, canvas, drawing

I'm making a silverlight website which includes paint-like features including freedraw. To achieve this I used the technique described on the following website: http://codeding.com/articles/freehand-drawing-in-silverlight .

The problem is, when I run the demo project it will start to lag extremely after just a few seconds of drawing. I realise that that is probably caused by the amount of shapes this techniue requires, however, and this is my main question:

How on earth does the demo on the website not lag nomatter howmuch I draw, while my local project which should have the EXACT same code lags right away?

I tried finding something about improving canvas performance overall, but the only thing I found was turning the drawing into a static image, which is not really ideal since I use undo/redo functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The number of shapes added to the `Canvas` shouldn't be the reason for the lagging, there must be something else like converting the drawing into image for undo/redo functionality. For undo/redo, you can save the strokes-information instead of images. Creating & storing images during each undo/redo operation will consume too much memory.

A stroke is nothing but a set of points from the start (mousedown event) to end (mouseup event), and a set of strokes forms a complete drawing. You can always recreate the drawing using the saved strokes-information (just like you can recreate using images). You can use simple data-structures like `List<List<Point>>` to store a complete drawing, this is very memory efficient instead of creating & storing the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. Unfortunately, in my tests I really didn't do anything else than add things to the canvas, just like the example code. And it still lags like hell after a few seconds of drawing. (PS: my current undo/redo is actually already the way you described it)